# How to change active directory password using Code?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, visual-web-part

How to change active directory User Account Password using code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't do this personally.

But you can as long as you have sufficient permissions something like:

```
DirectoryEntry myADUser = new
DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=User,CN=Users,DC=Domain,DC=com");
myADUser.Invoke("<opass>", "<npass>");
myADUser.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: where we have to pass username ?

Comment: what permission should the loggedin user have to perform this operation? Is it enough to use RWEP to perform this?

Comment: The Change Password permission in AD, on system and elevate the task, or not at all if its their own password by default I believe. You are best to go check with the Active Directory team what you are allowed to do.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an opensource webpart that enables users to change their password:

[ITaCS Change Password web part](http://changepassword.codeplex.com/)

I use this webpart myself and am satisfied about it.
The source code is available for viewing. It might inspire you for your own programming need.

Comment: I've been using this in production.  It works very well.  I recommend it and also recommend reviewing its code.

Comment: Project 'changepassword' was not found