# Upload picture folder or multiple pictures

Tags: 2013, picture-library

Is it possible to upload multiple pictures or picture folder?

In older version there is two choices: upload picture ,upload multiple pictures but for 2013 there is no multiple pictures or multiple documents choices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drag and drop multiple Files (pictures or documents) in SharePoint 2013.

Comment: I think it's because of the version difference. It is working with IE 10 but not working with IE 9. Thank you.

Comment: If you think my answer helped you then don't forgot to mark as answer.

Comment: @Torque check this for add password "http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/50614/how-to-change-active-directory-password-from-webpart"