# Password changing feature in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, user, password

How I can enable password changing feature for site's users in SharePoint 2013, so that each user can changed him/her password?

Comment: You want allow user to change their AD account's password change?

Comment: I created a username and password (in Windows Server) for each user that wants to access my site. Now, My users want to change their password by themselves through site, without login to Windows Server.

Comment: By windows Server means, Active Directory or local to server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is no OOB web part or application page avaliable for user self changing the password in AD in SharePoint, you need to create a SharePoint web part programmatically to let users reset their password in AD.

Their are two options

1. Create your own webpart and let the user to change their password. check these two posts.[links](http://glorix.blogspot.com/2007/10/ad-change-password-webpart.html) or [How to change active directory password using Code?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/50614/how-to-change-active-directory-password-from-webpart)
2. Or you can use the 3rd party option. [free from codeplex](http://changepasswordfromsharepoint2013.codeplex.com/) or [Bamboo solution](http://store.bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-password-change-web-part.aspx)

Comment: I downloaded the solution in free from codeplex site but I can not activate it. I get the error that says "This solution contains invalid markup or elements that cannot be deployed as part of a sandboxed solution. "

Comment: How you add the solutions?  Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath "E:\install\ChangePassword.wsp"
 
Install-SPSolution -Identity (Get-SPSolution | Where-Object{$_.Name -like "changepassword.wsp"}).SolutionId.Guid -GACDeployment

Comment: when I run  Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath "E:\install\ChangePassword.wsp", I get the output that shows the deployment state of solution is False.

Comment: 1st command just add it to the farm.then you need to run the 2nd command, which will deploy it.

Comment: It is  Deploying in Management Solution in Central Administration. How I can activate it for a collection site?

Comment: Once it added to Sharepoint and deployed(install) then you can go on your site collection and activate it...I beleive under site collection features

Comment: In solution part, in my site collection, this solution are not exist!

Comment: The solutions under Site Collection settings are the Sandboxed solutions. That is something different than the Farm Solution like "ChangePassword" you installed... There will be some feature that is now available under Site Collection Features because you installed the farm solution.

Comment: did you run the 2nd command? if yes then go to site action> site setting> manage site collection feature.

Comment: Yes, I ran it and I got error: "Install-SPSolution : Admin SVC must be running in order to create deployment"

Comment: you should fix this one first....from your windows server> services > make sure SharePoint Admin service is running

Comment: I fix this problem, but there is no changepassword feature in site action> site setting>manage site features

Comment: what about Site Collection features>

Comment: awesome!, i really happy your stuff is working.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can consider solution from [VirtoSoftware Password Changing](http://www.virtosoftware.com/products/administration/virto-password-change) (30-days free).