# The users can not change their passwords in AD-SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, active-directory, user-accounts, password

I used 3rd party option [free from codeplex](http://changepasswordfromsharepoint2013.codeplex.com/) to allow users changing their password themselves in my site collection. But when a user want to change his password, after entering new password, get the following error message:

```
The server could not be contacted.
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalServerDownException
System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapException: The LDAP server is unavailable. at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.Connect() at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.SendRequestHelper(DirectoryRequest request, Int32& messageID) at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.SendRequest(DirectoryRequest request, TimeSpan requestTimeout) at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.ReadServerConfig(String serverName, ServerProperties& properties)
Domain: sharepoint
```

Comment: You don't have the CodePlex solution set up properly, or it just doesn't work.  File an issue with them.

Comment: I agree with Derek, you will probably have better luck in getting an answer from the creators of the plugin

Comment: I used the instructions that stated in comments of this link: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118490/password-changing-feature-in-sharepoint-2013